# How to use procedure call and non-standard SQL in Business Intelligence Publisher (BIP)

Tags: sql, plsql, procedure, plsqldeveloper, bi-publisher

I have a function in my sql query. when I want to use it in BIP. I can use only standard SQL.
but I noticed there are two more options which are (procedure call) and (Non Standard SQL).
How to run my query. by using those two options.

the funtion (No info how to use it): CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_exchange_rate (....etc.)

The query (to run it in BIP):

```
NVL(SUM(ABS(DECODE(SIGN(ACCTD_AMOUNT_DUE_REMAINING*
      get_exchange_rate('USD', :P_CURRTO, a.TRX_DATE) ),-1,
      ACCTD_AMOUNT_DUE_REMAINING*
      get_exchange_rate('USD', :P_CURRTO, a.TRX_DATE) ,0))),0) CREDIT_AMOUNT,
```

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to use this function, and what error is it giving you, and where do you see the error?

Comment: What is the PL/SQL Developer issue?